# Bounded increments of a martingale converges proof.

Tags: uniform-convergence, martingales, random-walk

Prove or disprove:

There exists a martingale $\left(M_{n}\right)_{n}$ with $\mathbb{P}\left(M_{0}=1\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(M_{0}=-1\right)=1 / 2$ and $\left|M_{n}-M_{n-1}\right| \leq n^{-3}$ for all $n \geq 1$, such that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} M_{n}=0$ (almost surely)

**My attempt:**

Hey everyone, I am not sure of my thought process is right hence I wanted to check if I am heading down the correct path:

To prove the above statement:

Since  $\left(M_{n}\right)$ is a martingale then it is also a super martingale. Hence using Doob's martingale convergence theorem and since $\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}_{0}} \mathbb{E}\left[\left|M_{n}\right|\right] = 1 <\infty$ then $M_n$ converges almost surely to $M_\infty$. I feel like I might be wrong because its too simple and I am not sure how to show that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} M_{n}=0$. One way I thought of was using Monotone convergence theorem simply take the $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} |M_{n}-M_{n-1} \mid \leq n^{-3} = 0$. Sorry if I'm heading down the wrong path.

Comment: Why is $\sup E(|M_n|) = 0$? This already fails when $n =0 $, as $E|M_0| = 1$

Comment: @JoseAvilez Yes sorry, I accidentally did 0.5 - 0.5 instead of 0.5 - (-0.5) = 1. Updated my question. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @BrianMoehring It's an exercise I found to help me understand concepts about martingales. The exercise states to either prove or disprove the above statement.

Comment: Then you should disprove it.  You can use $\zeta(3) \approx 1.2021$ to show that $M_n$ cannot converge to $0$ in probability.  Start by giving a positive lower bound for $P(|M_1| \geq 1)$.

Comment: @JoseAvilez does it fail because since $M_n$ is a martingale hence it suppose to have a constant mean therefore $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} M_{n}$ is not equal to 0

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thank you for the suggestion! Could I also disprove it by saying since $M_n$ is a martingale, it has a constant mean of 1. Hence, $E[M_n]$ would be bounded above by 1 and below by 1 since a martingale is a submartingale and supermartingale. Therefore, $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} M_{n} \text { is not equal to }  0 $

Comment: No, because (1) $E[M_n] = 0$, not $1$. and (2) even if we had $E[M_n] =1$, this doesn't prevent $M_n \to 0$ almost surely without additionally showing, for instance, that $M_n$ converges in $L^1$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'm sorry but Im not quite sure how does $\text { giving a positive lower bound for } P\left(\left|M_{1}\right| \geq 1\right)$ help me disprove the statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since
$$
\mathsf{E}[M_1\mid M_0]=M_0,
$$
$$
\delta:= \mathsf{P}(M_1\ge 1\mid M_0=1)>0.
$$
Now, for $n\ge 2$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{P}(|M_n| > 0.1)&\ge \mathsf{P}(M_n>0.1) \\
&\ge \mathsf{P}(M_n>0.1, M_0=1,M_1\ge 1) \\
&=\mathsf{P}(M_n>0.1 \mid M_0=1,M_1\ge 1) \\
&\quad \times\mathsf{P}(M_0=1,M_1\ge 1) \\
&=1\times \delta/2 \not\to 0 
\end{align}
as $n\to\infty$.